# How to stop SwingWorker once dropbox list files are displayed in JList?

Tags: java, netbeans, dropbox, swingworker

I have a JList which shows the list of file in the dropbox account (Dropbox API v2).

The listing of the files works using the swingworker, however, I am able to stop or cancel the swingworker automatically once the task has been completed.

I have tried -> `task.cancel(true);` but it cancels the task before the list is fully loaded in the JList. Below is my coding that I have so far and I know I'm very close but just can't figure out how to cancel the task once it has loaded the file names successfully in the JList.

Please could someone help me out in terms of cancelling the task once it has completed.

```
private TaskLoadFiles tLoadtask;
    private class TaskLoadFiles extends SwingWorker<Void, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws InterruptedException
        {

            while (!isCancelled())
            {
                 try
                {

                    ListFolderResult resultdec = client.files().listFolder("/Data/");
                    //model used to stored the data for display
                    DefaultListModel modelListFilesdownloaddec = new DefaultListModel();
                    while (true) 
                    {
                        for (Metadata metadata : resultdec.getEntries()) {
                            //adds the data to the model --> gets the file names
                            modelListFilesdownloaddec.addElement(metadata.getName());
                            //displays the data from the model into the JList
                            listFilesDownloadBtndeccloud.setModel(modelListFilesdownloaddec);                                
                        }                            
                        if (!resultdec.getHasMore()) {
                            break;                                
                        }
                        resultdec = client.files().listFolderContinue(resultdec.getCursor());                                  
                    }
               }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to load cloud files. \nError : " + e, "Cloud Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }                    
            }
            return null;                
        }
        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            tLoadtask.cancel(true);                         
        }

        protected void process ()
        {

        }

    }
```

How will I go about solving this problem. I have read multiple different web pages based on the swingworker and questions posted on StackOverFlow, but just cannot solve this. Maybe there is a problem with the way I implemented the coding that it is not able to stop.

Much appreciated in advanced for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to cancel it, when it completed.
Just let it return from doInBackground.

What you are doing now is

```
while( !cancelled ){  // while #1
   while(true){       // while #2
       break; // out of while #2 if done
   }
}
```

It should be more like

```
while( !cancelled && !done ) // added a "done" flag
{
     doYourStuff();
     done = isComplete();
}
```

Disclaimer: Above snippets are **not** valid Java - just pseudo code for brevity.

By the way: using the "mayInterruptIf Running" flag ( see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel(boolean)) ) causes the worker to be interrupted (literally). So just set it to `false` and the loop will run to the next check of `isCancelled`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you for clarifying the problem that I had and was running. Your proposed solutions fixed the problem. Thanks again :) :) :)

Comment: thanks for your previous help. However, I have been experiencing a problem with the list loading. Sometimes the file name list from the cloud is loaded straight away and other times I need to click on a button 3 or 4 times then the list will show. Could you help me out in terms of why this is happening. Additionally, when I need to click on the button a 3 or 4 times then I get an exception thrown which is "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8". How can I fix this. much appreciated for your help.

Comment: Best is to open another question (you can link to this one for reference) in which you describe what the problem is and add stacktraces and your current code. So other people may also help.

Comment: I was playing around with the different coding for a long time. I did some research and found that the  if (!resultdec.getHasMore()) {                            break; } was there to indicate certain results of the actual method. So I solved it but placing listFilesDownloadBtndeccloud.setModel(modelListFilesdownloaddec); inside the if statement above and it was fixed. Anyways, thanks for all your help and helping me solve the problem. :):>)